# MySQL Cannot Show Column Name "Group"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which:

```
| fullname   | onepreference | group | batch |
+------------+---------------+-------+-------+
| First Name | 1             |   1   |  2015 |
| First Name | 2             |   1   |  2015 |
| First Name | 1             |   2   |  2007 |
| First Name | 4             |   2   |  2014 |
+------------+---------------+-------+-------+
```

I am trying to write the following query:

```
SELECT 
      fullname,  
      onepreference, 
      group 
 FROM mytable 
WHERE batch = 2015;
```

But it shows the following error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'group from mytable where batch=2015' at line 1

I think group column is a keyword of mysql. But I want to get the data of group column. Is there any possibilities available to take the group value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

group is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql. so you have to escape it with backticks:

```
select fullname, onepreference, `group` from add_application_form where batch=2015;
```

Answer (score 2):

`group` is a reserved word and you need to use backticks:

```
SELECT 
      fullname, 
      onepreference, 
      `group` 
 FROM add_application_form 
WHERE batch=2015;
```

Check the list **[here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)** and avoid those keyword as table and column names.